# Android dark mode detection in pure Node.js

Tags: node.js, termux, android-darkmode

I would like to detect dark mode on my android device running Node.js from termux.

Also I can't use electron, phantom.js or any other "rendering" library.

Is it possible?

If not I will accept any other possibility to get the device theme, using termux.

Edit: I opened a [request](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/issues/425) on the github page of termux-api